# SQLite3 Limitations for production use in a video game

Tags: sqlite

I have been using Unreal Engine 4 with SQLite3 for my game. It's a multiplayer game and the database would be stored on a digital ocean droplet. The server is the only thing that would read or write to the database. It's fully server authoritative.

However, I have gotten tons and tons of mixed information about SQLite's limitations for concurrent users and overall usability in a production system.

My plan is to have at maximum 100 concurrent users on the server connecting to the game.

The database is access whenever:
A player gets an item
A player places a building (base building feature)
The server does a periodical mass save of all (online players) player data (location, health...etc) -- This is all within a single table, each player is a row.
The player creates a certain type of structure and it creates a special table just for that object.
The player logs out
The player logs in
A new player is created

Is SQLite3 a good solution for what I am trying to do?

Comment: The question is not how many humans access the DB, but how many accesses are actually happening simultaneously. If you server serializes all requests, then the DB has one user.

Comment: Hey CL, the server makes requests periodically at different times based on whats going on. If the player picks up an item it updates the "player inventory table." This is just one example though.

Comment: CL is on the right track. Unless you are intentionally making things asynchronous in the server where they normally aren't by default then you shouldn't have to worry about concurrency much, as mostly it will be synchronous. I think maybe level streaming would go async loading but I don't remember if that is default or opt-in. If you plan to implement lots of async, choose carefully as sqlite does not handle concurrency well. Otherwise, your biggest concerns should be how often are you hitting the database and how long is your game waiting for execution to return from database code.